# How to prevent explorer window covering taskbar when fullscreen window is acivated?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a FullScreen window which is Maximized state when it is activated and if there are explorer window opened and dragged to the bottom behind taskbar it covers taskbar like in the picture here [image]

Here is my window code:

```
    <Window x:Class="Forms.DrawingWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Name="drawingWindow"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowStyle="None"
    Background="Transparent"
    Cursor="Cross"
    MouseDown="Window_MouseDown"
    MouseMove="Window_MouseMove"
    KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"
    Topmost="False" MouseLeftButtonUp="Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
    <Border Background="Black" Opacity="0.1" x:Name="fill"></Border>
    <Canvas x:Name="cnv" Background="Transparent">
        <Border x:Name="rect" Background="#19FFFFFF" Height="0" Width="0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="cords" Text="" Foreground="LightGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" FontFamily="Open Sans" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="10" />
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

There is nothing special in .cs code just this.Show();
Question is how to prevent explorer windows covering taskbar when they are behind it?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want. It creates a 'maximized' window without hiding the taskbar.

```
 FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        Left = Top = 0;
        Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
        Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
```

Comment: It's not a Form It's a Window. WIndow doesn't have FormBorderStyle. By the way I need that my window cover taskbar but not other open explorer windows like in image. You can see in the bottom image that my window covers everything with transparent.

Comment: @Rahul Ranjan: That is Windows Forms code. This is a WPF question.

Comment: @d4mn that means do you want the wpf window to remain on the top always?

Comment: Yes. But this is not the problem. The problem is that other explorer windows covers taskbar like in picture when my window is activated.